# Group actions, the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem and Burnside's Lemma.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Since I didn't feel confident about the subject as read so far, I've tried to deploy it somehow. This way I can go as far as the OST (Corollary 2), but I am stuck with the proof in Lemma 3, which is necessary to get to Burnside's Lemma (Corollary 3).

Could someone give me a hint how to prove the Lemma 3, please?

---

Driven by the "prototypical action" on a set, namely a permutation of its elements, we define *action of the group $G$ on the set $S$* the **map**:

\begin{alignat*}{1}
  G \times S &\longrightarrow& S \\
  (g,s)&\longmapsto& gs
\end{alignat*}

with the following properties:

1. $es=s, \forall s \in S$;
2. $g(hs)=(gh)s, \forall g,h \in G, \forall s \in S$.

Given $s,t \in S$, we say:

$$t \stackrel{\cdot}{\sim}s \stackrel{(def.)}{\Longleftrightarrow} \exists g \in G \mid t=gs \tag 1$$

By virtue of action's properties, $\stackrel{\cdot}{\sim}$ turns out to be an equivalence relation on $S$. In fact:

- $s \stackrel{\cdot}{\sim} s$, because $s=es$;
- $t\stackrel{\cdot}{\sim}s \Rightarrow t=gs \Rightarrow g^{-1}t=g^{-1}(gs)=(g^{-1}g)s=es=s \Rightarrow s\stackrel{\cdot}{\sim}t$;
- $(t\stackrel{\cdot}{\sim}s) \wedge (s\stackrel{\cdot}{\sim}r) \Rightarrow (t=gs) \wedge (s=hr) \Rightarrow t=g(hr)=(gh)(r) \Rightarrow t\stackrel{\cdot}{\sim}r$.

Thence, $S$ is partitioned into *orbits*:

$$\mathcal{O}:=S/\stackrel{\cdot}{\sim}=\lbrace O(s), s \in S\rbrace \tag 2$$

where

$$O(s):=[s]_{\stackrel{\cdot}{\sim}}=\lbrace t \in S \mid t\stackrel{\cdot}{\sim}s\rbrace=\lbrace t \in S \mid t=gs, g \in G \rbrace \tag 3$$

Given $s \in S$, distinct group's elements may "move" $s$ to one same element of $S$, and we say:

$$h\stackrel{s}{\sim}g \stackrel{(def.)}{\Longleftrightarrow} hs=gs \tag 4$$

$\stackrel{s}{\sim}$ is an equivalence relation on $G$; in fact:

- $g\stackrel{s}{\sim}g$, because $gs=gs$;
- $h\stackrel{s}{\sim}g \Rightarrow hs=gs \Rightarrow gs=hs \Rightarrow g\stackrel{s}{\sim}h$;
- $(h\stackrel{s}{\sim}g) \wedge (g\stackrel{s}{\sim}k) \Rightarrow (hs=gs) \wedge (gs=ks) \Rightarrow hs=ks \Rightarrow h\stackrel{s}{\sim}k$.

Thence, given $s \in S$, $G$ is partitioned into *stabilizers*:

$$\mathcal{S}_s:=G/\stackrel{s}{\sim}=\lbrace \mathcal{Stab}_s(g), g \in G\rbrace \tag 5$$

where

$$\mathcal{Stab}_s(g):=[g]_{\stackrel{s}{\sim}}=\lbrace h \in G \mid h\stackrel{s}{\sim}g\rbrace=\lbrace h \in G \mid hs=gs\rbrace \tag 6$$

---

**Lemma 1**. The map:

\begin{alignat*}{1}
  \chi \colon \mathcal{S}_s &\longrightarrow& O(s) \\
  \mathcal{Stab}_s(g) &\longmapsto& \chi(\mathcal{Stab}_s(g)):=gs \tag 7
\end{alignat*}

is well-defined and bijective.

*Proof*.

- Let $h \in \mathcal{Stab}_s(g)$; then, $\chi(\mathcal{Stab}_s(h))=hs=gs=\chi(\mathcal{Stab}_s(g))$, and $\chi$ is well-defined.
- $\chi(\mathcal{Stab}_s(h))=\chi(\mathcal{Stab}_s(g)) \Rightarrow hs=gs \Rightarrow h \in \mathcal{Stab}_s(g)$; but $h \in \mathcal{Stab}_s(h)$, then $\mathcal{Stab}_s(h)=\mathcal{Stab}_s(g)$, and $\chi$ is 1-1.
- By definition of $O(s)$, $\forall t \in O(s), \exists g \in G$ such that $t=gs=\chi(\mathcal{Stab}_s(g))$, and $\chi$ is onto. $\Box$

**Lemma 2**. $\forall g,h \in G$, the map:

\begin{alignat*}{1}
  \xi \colon \mathcal{Stab}_s(g) &\longrightarrow& \mathcal{Stab}_s(h) \\
  k &\longmapsto& \xi(k) :=hk^{-1}g \tag 8
\end{alignat*}

is bijective.

*Proof*. Firstly, $\forall k \in \mathcal{Stab}_s(g)$, it is $\xi(k) \in \mathcal{Stab}_s(h) \Leftrightarrow (hk^{-1}g)s=hs$, and this latter holds because $(hk^{-1}g)s=h(k^{-1}(gs))=h(k^{-1}(ks))=h((k^{-1}k)s)=h(es)=hs$. Besides, $\xi(k)=\xi(u)\Rightarrow k=u$, by group properties, and $\xi$ is 1-1. Finally, $\forall v \in \mathcal{Stab}_s(h)$, $v=\xi(gv^{-1}h)$, and $\xi$ is onto. $\Box$

**Corollary 1**. (Here $|X|$ stands for the cardinality of $X$.) $\forall g \in G$:

$$|\mathcal{Stab}_s(g)|=|\mathcal{Fix}(s)| \tag 9$$

where:

$$\mathcal{Fix}(s):=\lbrace h \in G \mid hs=s\rbrace \tag {10}$$

*Proof*. By the Lemma 2, $\forall g \in G, |\mathcal{Stab}_s(g)|=|\mathcal{Stab}_s(e)|$, and $\mathcal{Stab}_s(e)$ is precisely $\mathcal{Fix}(s)$. $\Box$

**Corollary 2. (Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem.)** If $G$ is finite, then:

$$|\mathcal{Fix}(s)||O(s)|=|G|, \forall s \in S \tag {11}$$

*Proof*. Given $s \in S$, $G$ is partitioned into $|O(s)|$ subsets (by Lemma 1) of $|\mathcal{Fix}(s)|$ elements each (by Corollary 1). $\Box$

For any $g \in G$, we call:

$$\operatorname{Fix}(g):=\lbrace s \in S \mid gs=s \rbrace \tag {12}$$

> *(EDIT on the basis of the accepted answer and therein comments.)*
>
> **Lemma 3**. If $G$ and $S$ are finite, then:
>
> $$\sum_{g \in G}|\operatorname{Fix}(g)|=\sum_{s \in
> S}|\mathcal{Fix}(s)| \tag {13}$$
>
> *Proof*. By $(10)$ and $(12)$:
>
> $$\lbrace \mathcal{Fix}(s) \times \lbrace s \rbrace, s \in S \rbrace = \lbrace (g,s) \in G \times S \mid gs=s \rbrace = \lbrace \lbrace g \rbrace \times \operatorname{Fix}(g), g \in G \rbrace$$
>
> from which $(13)$ follows for $G$ and $S$ finite. $\Box$

**Corollary 3. (Burnside's Lemma.)** If $G$ and $S$ are finite, then:

$$|\mathcal{O}|=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}|\operatorname{Fix}(g)| \tag {14}$$

*Proof*. By $(2)$ and $(11)$:

\begin{alignat}{1}
\sum_{s \in S}|\mathcal{Fix}(s)| &= \sum_{O(s) \in \mathcal{O}}\sum_{t \in O(s)}|\mathcal{Fix}(s)| \\
&= \sum_{O(s) \in \mathcal{O}}|\mathcal{Fix}(s)|\sum_{t \in O(s)}1 \\
&= \sum_{O(s) \in \mathcal{O}}|\mathcal{Fix}(s)||O(s)| \\
&= \sum_{O(s) \in \mathcal{O}}|G| \\
&= |G|\sum_{O(s) \in \mathcal{O}}1 \\
&= |G||\mathcal{O}| \tag {15}
\end{alignat}

and $(14)$ follows from the Lemma 3. $\Box$

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lemma 3 is the following observation.

Let $[P]$ be the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) of $P$, i.e., it is $1$ if $P$ is true, and $0$ if $P$ is false, where $P$ is a statement.

Then observe that 
$$|\operatorname{Fix}(g)|=\sum_{s\in S} [gs=s],$$ 
and that
$$|\mathcal{Fix}(s)| = \sum_{g\in G} [gs=s].$$

Thus we have
$$\sum_{g\in G}|\operatorname{Fix}(g)|=\sum_{g\in G}\sum_{s\in S} [gs=s] = \sum_{s\in S}|\mathcal{Fix}(s)|$$

Comment: +1. Didn't know there was a notation and a name for this $[P]$ ! (I usually just use $\mathbb{1}$ for indicator functions, as this is essentially what the bracket does)

Comment: Maybe I got your point: think of a set $A$ as a subset of a "universe-set" $U$, namely $A=\lbrace u \in U \mid P_A(u) \rbrace$, where $P_A$ is the characteristic property of $A$; now, if $U$ is finite, we get: $|A|=\sum_{u \in U}[P_A(u)]$. In our case, the two "Fix" sets belong to two different (finite) "universes" ($G$ and $S$) but share the same characteristic property. Is it so?

Comment: Not "belong to", I meant "are contained into".

Comment: @Luca I think your comment is essentially the idea yes. While the two fix sets are subsets of $G$ and $S$, since each of the fix sets are functions of a parameter from the other set, it might be more productive to think of them as being two different views of a single $g \text{ fix } s$ relation on $G\times S$, where we say $g\text{ fix } s$ if and only if $gs = s$. If you're familiar with probability, the fix sets are like integrating out one of the variables to obtain the marginal distribution on the other.

Comment: The equality we want is then like saying that if we integrate out both variables, we get the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, the point is clear to me now.