# Alternative Proof of Burnside's Lemma

Tags: group-theory, alternative-proof

I studied group theory a long time ago. Back then, I didn't understand how to use the group theory-specific idioms to write short proofs. I still don't.

Below is a proof of Burnside's Lemma using as little group theory as possible, by which I mean it uses few commonly-known lemmas. The basic thrust of the argument is showing that both sides count the number of fixed points of $\varphi(g)$ for each $g$ in the group $G$ .

*What are some good ways of proving Burnside's lemma without spending much ink and idiomatically using other results that are "more basic" than Burnside's Lemma?*

*I'm attaching below my proof of the lemma. I looked at Wikipedia to get the statement of the theorem, but did not read the proof section until I completed the proof.*

---

Proof of Burnside's lemma.

First a word on notation.

The notation $[\psi]$ for a proposition $\psi$ is $1$ if the expression is true and $0$ if the expression is false. It is called an [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

A group $G$ acts on a set $X$ . Equivalently, there exists a function $\varphi : G \to (X \to X) $ that sends each $g$ to a function from $X$ to itself. $\varphi$ is not required to be injective. $\varphi$ is not completely arbitrary; it satisfies some laws that I won't enumerate here.

Let $\langle g, x \rangle$ denote the group action.

$$ \langle g,x \rangle \stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=} (\, \varphi(g)\,)(x) $$

Let $G(x)$ denote the orbit of $x$ in $G$ .

$$ G(x) \stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=} \{ g \in G \;|\; \langle g, x \rangle \} $$

Let $\simeq_G$ be a binary predicate that is true if and only if there exists a $g$ that sends the left argument to the right argument.

$$ x \simeq_G y \stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{\iff} \left(\exists g \in G \mathop. \langle g, x \rangle = y \right) $$

Note that

$$ x \simeq_G y \iff x \in G(y) $$

and

$$ x \simeq_G y \iff y \in G(x) $$

Let's show that the negation of Burnside's Lemma is absurd.

$$ |X/G|\cdot|G| \ne \sum_{g \in G} |X^g| $$

$$ |X/G|\cdot|G| \ne \sum_{g \in G} \left|\left\{ x \in X | \langle g, x \rangle = x \right\}\right| $$

$$ |X/G|\cdot|G| \ne \sum_{g \in G}\sum_{x \in X} [\langle g, x \rangle = x ] $$

$$ |G|\cdot|X/G| \ne \sum_{g \in G}\sum_{x \in X} [\langle g, x \rangle = x ] $$

$$ |G|\cdot\sum_{x \in X} \frac{1}{|G(x)|} \ne \sum_{g \in G}\sum_{x \in X} [\langle g, x \rangle = x ] $$

$$ |G|\cdot\sum_{x \in X} \frac{1}{|G(x)|} \ne \sum_{g \in G}\sum_{x \in X}\sum_{y \in X} [\langle g, x \rangle = y ][ x = y ] $$

If we relax the restriction that $x = y$ and insist instead that $x \simeq_G y$, then we can count each $x$ at $\frac{1}{|G(x)|} = \frac{1}{|G(y)|}$ value.

$$ |G|\cdot\sum_{x \in X} \frac{1}{|G(x)|} \ne \sum_{g \in G}\sum_{x \in X}\sum_{y \in X} [\langle g, x \rangle = y ]\cdot\frac{[x \simeq_G y]}{|G(x)|} $$

However, the condition $x \simeq_G y$ is redundant if we already know that $\langle g, x \rangle = y$ for some particular $g \in G$ .

$$ |G|\cdot\sum_{x \in X} \frac{1}{|G(x)|} \ne \sum_{g \in G}\sum_{x \in X}\sum_{y \in X} [\langle g, x \rangle = y ]\cdot\frac{1}{|G(x)|} $$

$$ \sum_{x \in X} |G| \cdot \frac{1}{|G(x)|} \ne \sum_{g \in G}\sum_{x \in X}\sum_{y \in X} [\langle g, x \rangle = y ]\cdot\frac{1}{|G(x)|} $$

Replace $|G|$ with a sum counting $1$ for each item in $G$.

$$ \sum_{x \in X} \left( \sum_{g \in G} 1 \right) \cdot \frac{1}{|G(x)|} \ne \sum_{g \in G}\sum_{x \in X}\sum_{y \in X} [\langle g, x \rangle = y ]\cdot\frac{1}{|G(x)|} $$

The group element $g$ acting on the set $X$ sends a particular $x \in X$ to exactly one destination.

$$ \sum_{x \in X} \left( \sum_{g \in G} \sum_{y \in X} [\langle g, x \rangle = y] \right) \cdot \frac{1}{|G(x)|} \ne \sum_{g \in G}\sum_{x \in X}\sum_{y \in X} [\langle g, x \rangle = y ]\cdot\frac{1}{|G(x)|} $$

$$ \sum_{x \in X} \sum_{g \in G} \sum_{y \in X} [\langle g, x \rangle = y] \cdot \frac{1}{|G(x)|} \ne \sum_{g \in G}\sum_{x \in X}\sum_{y \in X} [\langle g, x \rangle = y ]\cdot\frac{1}{|G(x)|} $$

All sub-expressions are positive, we can reorder.

$$ \sum_{g \in G} \sum_{x \in X} \sum_{y \in X} [\langle g, x \rangle = y] \cdot \frac{1}{|G(x)|} \ne \sum_{g \in G}\sum_{x \in X}\sum_{y \in X} [\langle g, x \rangle = y ]\cdot\frac{1}{|G(x)|} $$

$$ \bot $$

Therefore $ | X/ G | \cdot |G| = \sum_{g \in G} |X^g| $ as desired.

Comment: Just as a style convention, it is somewhat confusing to write a proof using contradiction when your argument *does not* really rely on contradiction! A lot of beginning proof writers fall into the pitfall of using the following style: They want to show P is true. Then they assume P is not true. Then by using a direct argument, they show P is true and then claim it is a contradiction... but they aren't really contradicting anything! Therefore, it is more clear to write things directly. See if you can do that here by using the same proof to show |X/G|*|G| = sum |X^g| directly

Comment: Related, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3245386/group-actions-the-orbit-stabilizer-theorem-and-burnsides-lemma/3245409?noredirect=1#comment6674837_3245409

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

Prescribe  function $\chi:G\times X\to \mathbb\{0,1\}$ by stating that: $$\chi(g,x)=1\iff gx=x$$ Then automatically  $\chi(g,x)=0$ if $gx\neq x$.

Then the theorem of Burnside will show up if we work out the equality:$$\frac1{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\sum_{x\in X}\chi(g,x)=\frac1{|G|}\sum_{x\in X}\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g,x)$$

Give it a try.

---

**edit**:

Essential for working out the RHS is the following observation.

If $\mathcal{P}$ denotes a partition of finite set $X$ and for every
$x$ the $P\in\mathcal{P}$ with $x\in P$ is denoted as $\left[x\right]$
then: $$\sum_{x\in X}\frac{1}{\left[x\right]}=\sum_{P\in\mathcal{P}}\sum_{x\in P}\frac{1}{\left[x\right]}=\sum_{P\in\mathcal{P}}1=\left|\mathcal{P}\right|$$